# The largest digital sum of the square of an n-digit number

Tags: nt.number-theory, integer-sequences

The sequence $13, 31, 46, 63, 81, 97, 112, 130, 148, 162, 180, \dots,$ (sequence [A348300](https://oeis.org/A348300) in the OEIS) shows the largest digital sum the square of an $n$-digit (decimal) number has.

Is this sequence strictly increasing?

Comment: Did you check that for small $n$, say, $n<10^9$?

Comment: @markvs No, I only have those values for the sequence.

Comment: for the analogues sequence in base 2, namely $1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 13, 13, 15, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 25, 27, ...$ it is not strictly increasing, since $13, 13$ appears.

Comment: @markvs: What do you mean exactly? For $n=10^9$ one would have to compute the squares of about $10^{10^9-1}$ numbers. If you meant $n=9$ then the OP did do that.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch: You do not need squares of all numbers. I did mean $n\lt 10^9$. But if the OP can check it for other small $n$, it is fine. By the way, it is obvious that the sequence is not decreasing. The only question is whether $a_m$ can be equal to $a_{m+1}$.

Comment: @markvs Can you please elaborate on how exactly one might computationally check the case $n=10^9$ in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: @TimothyChow: I asked a question to the OP. Why do you think I should know the answer?

Comment: @markvs Your question was whether the OP checked $n< 10^9$ and I do not expect you to know whether the OP did in fact check $n < 10^9$. But saying that $n \approx 10^9$ is "small" implies that checking $n < 10^9$ is a feasible computation. When Yaakov Baruch asked for confirmation and pointed out that $n \approx 10^9$ does not appear to be a feasible computation, you affirmed that you did mean $n < 10^9$, and by saying, "You do not need squares of all numbers" you further implied that you had in mind some nontrivial way of making the computation feasible. I am just asking you for more details.

Comment: @TimothyChow: "you further implied" is purely your imagination. Clearly you do not need all squares. For example you do not need squares of numbers which are divisible by 10. There are many others which are not needed. $10^9$ is a small number for many similar questions. The OP gave first 10 values. But even the brute force (using some slow CAS) would give you $n=11$ in a few minutes.